# VBA Error 1004 - "Cannot access file" when opening workbook

Tags: vba

I am iterating a large directory of excel files (xls, xlsx, xlsm) and am running in to an issue on one of the files. I would like to just skip this file and any other files that show this same issue.

When the procedure attempts to open the file, I get a popup with the above error message. Below is the code, which should just skip over the error, but it doesn't help and the code stops executing.

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=filePath, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, Password:="", Editable:=False)
```

After the popup shows, I hold my mouse over line 2, and it shows "True" when it shouldn't. There is no other code that triggers upon events or that runs between turning off alerts and opening the workbook.

Opening the workbook manually, I find that access is denied by the server.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you,
James

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem, just check to rule it out.  Go to the VBA editor. From there click Tools -> Options -> General -> and make sure Error Trapping is set on "Break on unhandled errors" and not on either of the other options.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was already set to "Break on Unhandled Errors", so I wish this was the issue but it's not.